# Quotes being removed in rendered HTML from attributes

Tags: php, html, apache, debian

I have a Debian Lenny server, from where I run my websites - Zend Framework apps, Wordpress sites etc.

However, on all of my websites, regardless of what type, when I view source on ANY page, the quotation marks are not there for HTML attributes.

For example, if I even have a vanilla html file, say, text.html with the following basic contents sitting on the server:

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta name="content" value="Some value."/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.com/css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
</head>
```

When I view that page in a browser, there are no quotes around the *content* or *rel* attributes.

E.g., the rendered HTML is:

```
  <html>
<head>
<meta name=content value="Some value."/>
<link rel=stylesheet href="http://test.com/css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/>
</head>
```

I have googled for weeks, asked around but no-one has any idea what is causing this.
I have checked my php.ini file, there are no magic quotes, or stripslashes() etc enabled.

As it is every site I have, and every rendered page, I am thinking maybe an Apache config option, but everything looks OK to me.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated, as this is effecting my ranking on Yahoo and Bing, as for example they see no meta description tags (as the quotes are missing).

Thanks a lot,
Paul

**ANSWERED by asbjornu below - the problem was mod_pagespeed.**

Thanks again asbjornu!

Comment: Can you post a link to a plain HTML document where this behavior is demonstrated?

Comment: Sure thing - if you view source on this url: http://www.lottoresults.ie/text.html. Any page on the site exhibits the behaviour of missing quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) command reveals the following:

```
$ curl -I http://www.lottoresults.ie/text.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 22:01:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny13 with Suhosin-Patch
Last-Modified: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 21:27:25 GMT
ETag: "28a2f3-ad-4aef875018940"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Mod-Pagespeed: 0.9.8.1-215
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 167
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I'm pretty certain the `X-Mod-Pagespeed` header, which comes from [mod_pagespeed](http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/) is to blame. Look into mod_pagespeed's configuration, or deactivate the module completely (you might be able to do this within a [htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html), given the required permissions in [httpd.conf](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html)).

Comment: Thanks a million for that, seriously! Much appreciated, I was really stuck on that one - cheers.

Comment: If this was the solution to your problem, I'd appreciate if you could mark my answer as the correct solution. :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought I had! First time poster, so wasn't sure what to do there. For the record, I deleted pagespeed.conf and pagespeed.load from /etc/apache2/mods-enabled, and that did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could be of assistance. :)